# "Anfang des 20. Jahrhunderts" or "anfangs des 20. Jahrhunderts"?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

I'd like to know which term is correct:

> "Die historische Grundlage für das Unternehmen $foo liegt **anfangs** des 20. Jahrhunderts im Unternehmen $bar."
>   "Die historische Grundlage für das Unternehmen $foo liegt **Anfang** des 20. Jahrhunderts im Unternehmen $bar."

Comment: Wenn, dann hieße das: "am Anfang des 20. Jahrhunderts"  - Ohne "am" ist das mA nach sprachlich falsch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Korrekt ist aus meiner Sicht *Anfang des 20. Jahrhunderts*. Hierdurch wird ein mehr oder weniger genauer Zeitpunkt bestimmt.

Normalerweise kann man *anfangs* durch *zunächst* ersetzen. Tut man das, ergibt der Satz in Deinem Beispiel aber keinen Sinn mehr. *Anfangs* alleine kann gewissermaßen auch einen Zeitpunkt bestimmen (nämlich den, als etwas angefangen hat). Aber eine genauere Eingrenzung muss anders erfolgen:

> Anfangs, als wir frisch eingezogen waren, ...
>   Anfangs, zur Zeit Kaiser Wilhelm II., ...

Beispiele für Zeitpunkte mit *Anfang/Ende/Mitte*:

> Anfang des 20. Jahrhunderts
>   Ende der 80er Jahre
>   Mitte der 90er Jahre

Beispiele für *anfangs/zunächst*:

> Wir sind Kanu gefahren. Anfangs/zunächst ging das auch gut.
>   Joggen ist gesund. Anfangs sollte man jedoch noch nicht voll belasten.

Falsch aus meiner Sicht:

> Anfangs des Jahres
>   Joggen ist gesund. Anfangs des Trainings sollte man jedoch ...

Comment: Okay, vielen Dank für den fundierten Input! Ich werde das so verwenden.

Comment: @user24711 Wenn du das so verwenden willst, dann schreib' lieber "am Anfang des 20ten Jahrhunderts - Das "am" fehlt nämlich in deinem Beispiel.

Answer (score 2):

"Anfang" is the correct form to use as a "modifier," (for des 20. Jahrhunderts).
The phrase would be:

> Anfang des 20. Jahrhunderts... At the beginning of the 20th century...

"Anfangs" would be used for "at the beginning," when it is used as a "standalone" and not modifying anything:

> Anfangs, wenn er nicht so oft gekommen ist. "Anfangs" is followed by a comma, and is separated from the rest of the sentence.

The construction is a genitive construction, "Anfang des." That is the way it is used in the first example, "Anfang des 20. Jahrhunderts."

In the second example, where "anfang des" is a "standalone," set off by a comma, the contraction is "anfangs."